# How to refresh Scrapy request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am coding my first python project with Scrapy. I want to make a script that monitors a website and alerts me when a button on the webpage has changed, for example, a disabled button becoming enabled.

If I use a loop in the parse function, the code will loop over the initial response giving me the same outcome every time. How do I get Scrapy to generate a new request with every loop?  Inside the scrapy shell, I can use fetch to do so, is there a similar command I can use in the crawler?

```
def parse(self, response):
        yield {
        'current_state' : response.xpath("///div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[2]/text()").get()
        }
```

Comment: Can you share target link?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
import scrapy
from time import sleep


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'exampleSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://scrapingclub.com/exercise/detail_basic/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'title': response.xpath('//h3/text()').get()}
        # replace with your stopping condition
        if True:
            sleep(1)
            yield scrapy.Request(response.url, dont_filter=True)
```